# Dataframe if case based on its previous elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create the following "algorithm"

```
df['x'] = np.where(sum(df['x'][i-1],3)>10, 10, 5)
```

The idea here is that if the rolling sum of the last 3 elements, starting from the previous one, is positive then 5 else 10. I am looking for a data frame style solution without loops. Caution: df['x'] does not exist previously; it is a new column. So the result should be like that:

```
x
5
5
5
10
10
.
.
.
10
```

Comment: I don't get how you expect to take a rolling sum on a column that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rolling function available in Pandas.

df.loc[df['column_you_want_to_use_for_rolling'].rolling(3).sum() > 0, 'x'] = 5

You can change the conditions to suit your requirements.